# How to get arguments from githook?

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks, pre-commit-hook

From the [githook's doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) says:

> Hooks can get their arguments via the environment, command-line arguments, and stdin. See the documentation for each hook below for details.

But what are the mentioned arguments?

If I do commit with this command:

```
git commit -m "my commit" --trailer "Helped-by: Nganu <committer@example.com>"
```

How to get `trailer` value in pre-commit or prepare-commit-msg hook?

I don't see any documentation about getting arguments in `pre-commit` or `prepare-commit-msg` hooks. And I tried using `$0` like bash argument, but it failed.

Comment: You cannot provide arbitrary command-line arguments and expect them to be sent to your hook. When it says, "Hooks can get their arguments via the environment, command-line arguments, and stdin", it means *git* provides arguments to your hooks using one or more of these mechanisms. The actual arguments determined by `git` (e.g., `prepare-commit-message` takes one to three parameters, but `pre-commit` takes no parameters; see `githooks(5)` for more information).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `prepare-commit-msg`,

> It takes one to three parameters. The first is the name of the file
> that contains the commit log message. The second is the source of the
> commit message, and can be: message (if a -m or -F option was given);
> template (if a -t option was given or the configuration option
> commit.template is set); merge (if the commit is a merge or a
> .git/MERGE_MSG file exists); squash (if a .git/SQUASH_MSG file
> exists); or commit, followed by a commit object name (if a -c, -C or
> --amend option was given).

We can get the file that contains the commit message log from the first parameter, and then parse it to get the trailers.

```
#!/bin/bash

msg_file=$1
echo msg_file:${msg_file}

# parse msg_file to get trailers
trailer=$(git interpret-trailers --parse ${msg_file} | grep '^Helped-by:')
echo Trailer: ${trailer}
```